# Enumerate all objects of the specified type using reflection

Tags: .net, reflection

How do I enumerate all objects (of the specified type) in the process using reflection?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @zerkms, it's for my diagnostic tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime library http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/05/01/net-crash-dump-and-live-process-inspection.aspx
For example:

```
    int pid = Process.GetProcessesByName("HelloWorld")[0].Id;
    using (DataTarget dataTarget = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(pid, 5000))
    {
        string dacLocation = dataTarget.ClrVersions[0].TryGetDacLocation();
        ClrRuntime runtime = dataTarget.CreateRuntime(dacLocation);

        ClrHeap heap = runtime.GetHeap();
        foreach (ulong obj in heap.EnumerateObjects())
        {
            ClrType type = heap.GetObjectType(obj);
            ulong size = type.GetSize(obj);
            Console.WriteLine("{0,12:X} {1,8:n0} {2}", obj, size, type.Name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
if (list is System.Collections.IEnumerable)
{                      
  foreach (object obj in (list as System.Collections.IEnumerable))
  {

  }    
 }    
}
```